# Is it possible to optimize a large amount of BindValue in PDO by means of loops?

Tags: php, pdo

I have website with sudoku. Users can save their sudoku's to finish later. I would like to optimize or shorten my code. a1, a2, a3...[...] are the "name" of the individual fields in sudoku. I use PDO library.

This is the php code that saves all sudoku fields to the database:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO rozw 
                (user_id, id_wynik, 
                a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, 
                b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, 
                c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, 
                d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, 
                e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, 
                f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, 
                g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, 
                h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8, h9, 
                i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9) 
        VALUES (:user_id, :id_wynik, 
                :a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7, :a8, :a9, 
                :b1, :b2, :b3, :b4, :b5, :b6, :b7, :b8, :b9, 
                :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4, :c5, :c6, :c7, :c8, :c9, 
                :d1, :d2, :d3, :d4, :d5, :d6, :d7, :d8, :d9, 
                :e1, :e2, :e3, :e4, :e5, :e6, :e7, :e8, :e9, 
                :f1, :f2, :f3, :f4, :f5, :f6, :f7, :f8, :f9, 
                :g1, :g2, :g3, :g4, :g5, :g6, :g7, :g8, :g9, 
                :h1, :h2, :h3, :h4, :h5, :h6, :h7, :h8, :h9, 
                :i1, :i2, :i3, :i4, :i5, :i6, :i7, :i8, :i9)");

    $query->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':id_wynik', $_POST['id_wynik'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a1', $_POST['a1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a2', $_POST['a2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a3', $_POST['a3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a4', $_POST['a4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a5', $_POST['a5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a6', $_POST['a6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a7', $_POST['a7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a8', $_POST['a8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':a9', $_POST['a9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':b1', $_POST['b1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b2', $_POST['b2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b3', $_POST['b3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b4', $_POST['b4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b5', $_POST['b5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b6', $_POST['b6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b7', $_POST['b7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b8', $_POST['b8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':b9', $_POST['b9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':c1', $_POST['c1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c2', $_POST['c2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c3', $_POST['c3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c4', $_POST['c4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c5', $_POST['c5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c6', $_POST['c6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c7', $_POST['c7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c8', $_POST['c8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':c9', $_POST['c9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':d1', $_POST['d1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d2', $_POST['d2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d3', $_POST['d3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d4', $_POST['d4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d5', $_POST['d5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d6', $_POST['d6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d7', $_POST['d7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d8', $_POST['d8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':d9', $_POST['d9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':e1', $_POST['e1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e2', $_POST['e2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e3', $_POST['e3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e4', $_POST['e4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e5', $_POST['e5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e6', $_POST['e6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e7', $_POST['e7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e8', $_POST['e8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':e9', $_POST['e9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':f1', $_POST['f1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f2', $_POST['f2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f3', $_POST['f3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f4', $_POST['f4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f5', $_POST['f5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f6', $_POST['f6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f7', $_POST['f7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f8', $_POST['f8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':f9', $_POST['f9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':g1', $_POST['g1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g2', $_POST['g2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g3', $_POST['g3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g4', $_POST['g4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g5', $_POST['g5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g6', $_POST['g6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g7', $_POST['g7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g8', $_POST['g8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':g9', $_POST['g9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':h1', $_POST['h1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h2', $_POST['h2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h3', $_POST['h3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h4', $_POST['h4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h5', $_POST['h5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h6', $_POST['h6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h7', $_POST['h7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h8', $_POST['h8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':h9', $_POST['h9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->bindValue(':i1', $_POST['i1'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i2', $_POST['i2'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i3', $_POST['i3'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i4', $_POST['i4'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i5', $_POST['i5'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i6', $_POST['i6'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i7', $_POST['i7'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i8', $_POST['i8'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindValue(':i9', $_POST['i9'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->execute();
```

Can I shorten this code somehow using loops? Any suggestions?

And how to do it?

Comment: Yes of course you could

Comment: But of course such a table structure screams of improper database design. Consider normalizing your database.

Comment: @Your Common Sense

Why do you think my table is incorrect? I have a "rozw" table with cells a1, a2, a3 ... which correspond to each field in sudoku. How should I rebuild it?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want

```
$query->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':id_wynik', $_POST['id_wynik'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
$max = 9;

foreach ($alpha as $a){
    for ($n=1; $n<=$max; $n++) {
        $query->bindValue(":$a$n", $_POST[$a$n], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code generate error. I changed $_POST['$a$n] to  $_POST[''.$a.''.$n.''] and now work fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an associative array as a parameter to the `execute` method:

```
$data = [
    ':user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
    ':id_wynik' => $_POST['id_wynik'],
];

foreach (range('a', 'i') as $row) {
    foreach (range(1, 9) as $col) {
        $key = $row . $col;
        $data[$key] = $_POST[$key];
    }
}

$query->execute($data);
```

Comment: But them the values are treated as strings I believe and not integers

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are correct. while this will work, the values will be treated as strings and MySQL will have to convert it to int. since it's not too many values, the performance impact will probably be negligible, but your answer is better

Answer (score 2):

```
$colNames = '';
$colValus = '';
$charArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i');
foreach($charArray as $key => $char)
{
    for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++)  
    {
        $colNames  .= ',' . $char . $i; 
        $colValues .= ':' . $char . $i;    
    }
}
$sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO rozw (user_id, id_wynik, ' . $colNames . ' VALUES (:user_id, :id_wynik, ' . $colValues . '))';
$query->bindValue(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':id_wynik', $_POST['id_wynik'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
foreach($charArray as $key => $char)
{
    for($i=1; $i<=9; $i++)  
    {
        $colVal  = ':' . $char . $i;
        $postVal = $char . $i;
        $query->bindValue($colVal , $_POST[$postVal], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    }
}

$query->execute();
```